# @Transaction at Service layer not working on DAO layer in spring

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am using @Transactional (org.springframework.transaction.annotation) at the service method from where I call the DAO layer to fetch data from DB.

However, I am getting following error

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
```

on

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
```

I have added package scanning to different files as suggested by other posts.Still unable to get the error.

Please help.Thanks a million in advance.

Following are the files I have used.

applicationContext.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.BASE_PCKG"></context:component-scan>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.BASE_PCKG.SUB_PCKG.web"></context:component-scan>
```

Web.xml

```
...
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
....
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Also I have configured the transaction manager in applicationContext file as :

```
<bean id="txManager"          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" primary="true">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

Comment: Do you have spring-boot in your classloader?  How you configure your hibernate?

Comment: did you defined transactionManager in your config file for the sessionFactory? Also include <tx:annotation-driven/>  in config file

Comment: how you configure hibernate's context ? how you configure the transaction manager?

Comment: I am not using spring-boot and have also defined the transaction manager.

Comment: Did anyone found an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Add @Transactional on daoImpl class and Add transaction manager in configuration file:

```
<tx:annotation-driven/> 

<bean id="transactionManager" 
 class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Already added. Also, service layer needs to be Transactional not the DAO layer.

Comment: But that's not required.

Answer (score -1):

Calling the method via proxy would help and fix the issue.
Calling the same method from same class would not help transaction work.